# In hiredis async, can event_base_dispatch(base) be called from a different thread?

Tags: redis, hiredis

This query is with respect to the [example](https://github.com/redis/hiredis/blob/master/examples/example-libevent.c) provided in hiredis

Can event_base_dispatch(base) be called from a different thread by creating pthread_create()?

It is a fact that event_base_dispatch() is a loop and it is a blocking call. My idea here is to send all my redis command from the parent thread by invoking redisAsyncCommand(), event base will be run in the other thread.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use add enable_thread_safe_windows function before you create a event base.